# NDB Cluster Migration

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I am having problem with NDB Migration. Currently, I have 2 replicas in NDB Cluster. I want to move the cluster into a new hardware. So, in the new machine I setup datanodes and sqlnodes & pointed the management node to the old cluster. Once the sql nodes gets sync, I shall stop the old cluster. I am thinking this way. Does it work? Can we make more that two replicas in NDB cluster (like 3,4)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only method to perform a move to new HW without downtime
is by ensuring that the new HW has the same IP addresses as the old
HW.

So stop one node in the old cluster. Move the IP address of this machine
to the machine to take over this role among the new HW. Next start this
machine with an initial node restart (for data nodes).

Next take care of the next machine in the same manner one at a time until
all nodes have been changed.

If this is not possible I don't think there is anything else than
backup and restore that works.

Comment: Brother, none of the methods worked for me. When I tried the backup & restore method, the following error occurred:

Answer (score 0):

There is one more method you can use to move to new HW.
In this case you setup MySQL Cluster Replication to the new
cluster. After getting the new cluster up and running you
can switch over to the new cluster. This is the method used
by most people when performing complex upgrades.